# Kaboom.js check object sprite type ? object.is?

Tags: events, kaboom

I am creating a game with kaboom.js and wanted to check an object in the `player.onHeadbutt((obj) => { if(object.is('surprise-block')) {...} })` callback, but apparently that method does not exist? I was doing a tutorial based on a 6 month old youtube video.. did the library change that much since then?
And if so, I then feel like it's not maintained very well.. are there more recommended game library alternatives than kaboom.js?

Furthermore.. where can I check which version of kaboom.js I have and how can I check what object sprite type I am interacting with?

I wanted to destroy the sprite on headbutt and replace it with another sprite...

Answer (score 0):

I just found out how it's done:

```
player.onHeadbutt((obj) => {
    const x = obj.pos.x;
    const y = obj.pos.y;
    add([
        pos(x, y),
        sprite("coin"),
    ])
    obj.destroy()
})
```

You have to add pos(x,y) before adding the sprite.. didn't know that was important...